# RSpec: Problems converting to the new "allow" syntax for mocks/stubs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, stub

I am trying to learn rspec and apply what I am learning to an existing rails app.

I am trying to create a mock of a user called "current_user"

I have basically taken this line of code

```
     controller.stub(:current_user).and_return(build_stubbed(:user))
```

and placed it before my tests (all of which require a current_user to be defined)

This works. But

1. I know that this syntax is deprecated and I should be using

   ```
     allow().to receive().and_return()
   ```

syntax but I can't seem to convert it to the new syntax and get it to work.

I tried

```
    user = double("user")
    allow(user).to receive(:current_user).and_return(build_stubbed(:user))
```

without success. I reality I have no idea what I am doing with this and need to be pointed in the right direction. I have looked extensively for an answer but I suspect this is too basic.

Would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you're stubbing the `current_user` method for your `controller` variable. In your new syntax example, you've put the stub on the `user` double object.

Without knowing more about `build_stubbed`, I would expect it to look like:

```
allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return build_stubbed(:user)
```

Comment: This works. So to clarify, if this was written in english, its saying.... "allow the controller to have a method called current_user and respond to a call on that method with a user object"?

Comment: Yeah, that sums it up pretty well.